# EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' - Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am migrating to manifest v3, I added all needed content security policy to manifest.json file. However I received the following error :

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
> unsafe-eval is not an allowed source of script in the following
> Content Security Policy directive: script-src self.
>
> at eval ()
> at inboxsdk.js:1177

manifest.json :

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": false,
      "css": [ "css/content.css", "style.css", "css/buttons.css" ],
      "include_globs": [ "*://mail.google.*/*" ],
      "js": [ "resources/jquery-3.3.1/jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "js/api.js", "js/inpage.js", "js/menus.js", "js/content.js", "js/background.js", "lib/q.js", "js/inboxsdk.js", "js/app.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://*/*", "<all_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
  "manifest_version": 3,
 "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages":" object-src 'self'",
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; https://apis.google.com https://apis.google.com/js/client.js https://ajax.googleapis.com https://designshack.net/favicon.ico https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com https://tarruda.github.com  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://ydn-src-2.storage.googleapis.com  https://www.google.com/  ; default-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
```

Comment: MV3 doesn't allow content scripts to use eval.

Comment: what can i do ?

Answer (score -1):

Please update your "extension_pages":" object-src 'self'", with the below line of code

"extension_pages":"script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",